# Service Worker Cache Issue After Updating Angular Website

Tags: angular, caching, service-worker, angular-service-worker

#### Description:

I have implemented a Service Worker for my Angular frontend, and it has been functioning well. However, after updating my website, users with the old Service Worker cache in their browsers encounter errors, necessitating a manual page reload. This defeats the purpose of the Service Worker. I am seeking guidance on resolving this cache-related issue.

#### Problem:

When users have the previous version of my website saved in their browser, the outdated Service Worker cache persists, preventing the updated website from functioning as intended. Users are then required to manually refresh the page, which is not the desired behavior.

#### Question:

1. Is there a way for my Service Worker to detect and replace the old cache automatically when the website is updated?
2. If not, what strategies can be employed to ensure a seamless experience for users without requiring manual cache clearing?

#### Additional Notes:

- I have considered cache-busting techniques but seek advice on best practices.
- Are there specific considerations for Angular 14 and Service Worker 14.3.0 that might be relevant to this issue?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this Service Worker cache problem would be greatly appreciated.